# Performance difference between synchronous and AJAX calls

Tags: ajax, performance, synchronous

I have a normal HTTP request (no Ajax) and I return a response from server side. This takes around 350ms. The same response when returned through an Ajax call takes only 50 ms.

I checked also the processing or the time taken to prepare the response on the server side. This time is the same for both the requests. (For example, in both cases MyServlet handles the request and returns the response. I gave sysout in the doPost method and the time spent inside the Servlet is the same).

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are aware, that AJAX is asynchronous? Could it be that you are measuring the time  the call returns (should return immediately) and not until an actual response is received (onSuccess event called)?

Comment: no i am measuring in the onsuccess event only.. there is something else.. Sorry for the late reply

Comment: Then you should run Wireshark and check what's really going on.